# OPCACHE memory_consumption Error in Apache

Tags: php, windows, apache, opcache

Whenever I set the **opcache.memory_consumption** to use more than **1536MB** of RAM, my Apache returns the following error:
**Fatal Error Unable to create file mapping**

I use:

```
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition
PHP: MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
PHP: x64
PHP: Version 5.6.7
Apache/2.4.12 (Win64) - WinNT
Apache Lounge VC11 Server Built: Mar 20 2015 11:22:29
```

Does anyone know what could be?

Follows current configuration that works:

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=0
opcache.memory_consumption=1536
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=32
opcache.max_accelerated_files=40960
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=5
opcache.use_cwd=1
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=3
opcache.revalidate_path=0
opcache.save_comments=1
opcache.load_comments=1
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_file_override=0
opcache.optimization_level=0xffffffff
opcache.dups_fix=0
opcache.blacklist_filename=
opcache.max_file_size=0
opcache.consistency_checks=0
opcache.force_restart_timeout=180
opcache.error_log=
opcache.log_verbosity_level=1
opcache.preferred_memory_model=
opcache.protect_memory=0
```